# Ошибка при маппинге связи ManyToOne с bigserial id

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Есть таблица Events

```
------------------------------
|       id (bigserial)       |<-----
------------------------------     |
|   name (character varying) |     |
------------------------------     |
|        parent (fk)         |------
------------------------------
```

И модель Event

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "event_generator", sequenceName = "event_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "event_generator")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 150)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Event parent;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Event> children;

    public Event() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Event getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Event parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Event> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Event> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

При запуске вылетает ошибка в колонке parent:

Exception while preparing the app : Wrong column type in public.events for column parent. Found: int4, expected: int8

При изменении типа данных у id на Integer ошибка меняется и возникает уже в колонке id:

Exception while preparing the app : Wrong column type in public.events for column id. Found: bigserial, expected: int4

С любыми другими типами данных, ошибка такая же, как с Integer: Found bigserial, expected float4/float8/numeric(19, 2)/...

проперти в persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="200"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

Вопрос - как исправить чтобы все корректно маппилось?

Стэктрейс при типе данных Long

```
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Wrong column type in public.event for column parent. Found: int4, expected: int8
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in public.event for column parent. Found: int4, expected: int8
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1336)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Какая у Вас БД? У меня на Oracle такой ошибки не получилось. Маппинг по умолчанию в Hibernate указан для каждого диалекта отдельно в файле класса xxxxxDialect.java. Например, H2Dialect.java, Oracle9Dialect .java. А пробовали установить тип BigInteger?

Comment: PostgreSQL. BigInteger пробовал, ошибка меняется на Found bigserial, expected numeric(19, 2). Диалекты пробовал ставить PostgreSQLDialect и PostgreSQL82Dialect, но ничего не дало

Comment: Сообщите, пожалуйста, полный стек ошибок

Comment: Добавил. Плюс, поправил вопрос. Оказалось, что при типе данных Long ошибка возникала в столбце parent, а при изменении типа данных на любой другой - в id

Comment: A какая версия HIBERNATE-CORE

Comment: у меня его вообще не было, был только hibernate-entitymanager 5.4.1. Сейчас добавил hibernate-core 5.4.0. Ошибка видоизменилась, но суть осталась прежней - Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [parent] in table [event]; found [int4 (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [int8 (Types#BIGINT)]

Comment: Hibernate-entitymanager в последних версиях пустой jar (проверьте это). Все перенесено в Hibernate-core, как его у Вас.могло не быть я не понимаю. Судя по стеку, который Вы приложили у Вас была старая версия. А какого типа у Вас поле parent в таблице. Просьба выложить точную структуру таблицы и стек ошибок с новой версией core.

Comment: Изначально версия была 4.3.1, которая включала в себя core такой же версии. Вместо нее я добавил 5.4.1 и добавил core 5.4.0.
Ошибка оказалась в базе, в колонке parent тип данных был integer, вместо bigint. Спасибо за помощь